# Creating 3 Scrollable grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a webpage like the mockup I've posted. I tried looking for some jquery libraries that can help me achieve this task, but havent found any yet.

The idea is to make three separate scrollable grids, all three should occupy the entire browser screen, and the header bars should be able to hold text at the center.

Any help that would put me in the right direction will be a great help.

[image: Sample Mockup]

Comment: You can use this jQuery plugin: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: I had seen this as well but it doesnt work with internet explorer

Comment: I test in ie7 & ie8 and work: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TFJLd/3/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this plugin: jScrollPane / http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Demo in jsfiddle: http://goo.gl/hG9CV

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3vdS3/1/) is what I ended up using. But I dont know why they have a space between the divs. I cannot figure out how to fix it

Comment: Its a bootstrap padding, try .row-fluid [class*="span"]{ margin-left:0%!Important;} / http://jsfiddle.net/3vdS3/5/

Comment: Use bootstrap customize: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and @gridGutterWidth in 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do this using jquery, Simple CSS would work, just use `position:fixed` to position the divs and `overflow:scroll` to create scrollable element.

See a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJ4uV/)